# Is there any way to use custom tags to ignore proper tests in Specflow

Tags: c#, cucumber, specflow

Due to the development our team provide the automation coverage of a product for web and desktop environments via SpecFlow, Selenium and Appium. To simplify the automation framework we decide to reuse the existing Specflow scenarios for both web and desktop. However, some of the existing Specflow scenarios are not able to be automated because lots of issues with appium driver possibilities. So that, there is the necessity to use some kind of Specflow @ignore tag to skip some test scenarios during the test run for desktop, but these scenarios should be still able to be run for web env. I tried to google that, but found nothing relating to my issue.
Probably, some of you, guys, have the solution of this problem and can give me an advice to resolve it?

Comment: You are using junit?

Comment: How about duplicating those test, ones with @ignore tag, and others without? And change name of scenarios so they differ, or put them in different feature files. Or you can make new project (.dll), one for web and one for desktop, depending of your needs. If you make two dlls, consider including steps from different assembly (dll). You do that in configuration file (app.config, json).

Comment: Which unit test provider are you using?

Comment: Actually, our test framework include more then 500 tests, so it's impossible to use duplicates of the same tests. The only way to resolve the problem is to use the separate assembly for desktop, however this approach wasn't approved by technical lead and customers. Also, the tests run on Jenkins in scope of CI/CD, so it's impossible to comment single tests or use the @ignore tag for them, cause for now only the minority of test scenarios are stable for desktop run. The test provider is NUnit.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to utilize custom tag to ignore test but you will have to use specFlow internal interface `IUnitTestRuntimeProvider` and write logic in the binding to ignore test at runtime.

In feature file

```
  @ignore
  Scenario: mobile scenario
  Given some common step for web and mobile
```

In binding class `BindingClass`

```
public static ScenarioContext _scenarioContext;
```

Binding class constructor

```
 public BindingClass(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
        {
            _scenarioContext = scenarioContext;
        }
```

And here is the binding

```
 [Given(@"some common step for web and mobile")]

  public void someTest(){
      if (BindingClass.scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Tags.ToString().Contains("ignore"))
            {
                var unitTestRuntimeProvider = (IUnitTestRuntimeProvider)
                BindingClass._scenarioContext.GetBindingInstance((typeof(IUnitTestRuntimeProvider)));
                unitTestRuntimeProvider.TestIgnore("ignored");
            }
        else {

               //initiate appium driver or webDriver
            }
  }
```

This will ignore test if it finds `@ignore` tag on scenario in feature file . You can still have other tags on scenario. It will ignore test only if it finds `@ignore` . For web scenarios you can just remove `@ignore`

```
  Scenario: web scenario
  Given some common step for web and mobile
```